# Phantom won't open a url that is accessible (but will open it with fiddler running)

Tags: ssl, phantomjs

I have a very simple phantom script that pretty much just opens a url and dumps the html to console (not actually, but I've narrowed the problem down to this):

```
page.open op.url, (status) ->
    console.log "opened #{op.url}"
    console.log page.evaluate -> document.all[0].outerHTML
    phantom.exit()
```

When the url is `https://latestcommit-negotiate-demo.owex.com` phantomjs just hangs and never invokes the `page.open` callback. The site definitely exists and I can hit its login page in any of a dozen different ways but not with phantom!

What's especially bizarre is that I want to see whats going on over the wire - so I open up fiddler and...it starts working. As long as fiddler is open my script works great. The second I close it, it hangs on `page.open` again.

This is phantom 1.9.7 and I'm invoking it with the `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` flag.

Short of "something something ssl?" I'm at the limit of my knowledge. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that our server was not doing https via sslv2 but (surprisingly) via tlsv1. Fiddler was unwrapping the https envelope and rewrapping it with ssl. Adding a `--ssl-protocol=any` flag solved the issue.